# Custom ModelViewSet

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to add permissions to ModelViewSet and restrict the current user ("Waiter") role from create and delete categories but dont know how to work with the mixins. Could you help?

Here is the view:

```
class CategoriesFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = (
            'name', 'description', 'created_by__id', 'updated_by__id', 'parant__id')


class CategoriesModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Categories.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoriesModelSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination  # ?offset=0&limit=2 <= add this to the url field to test you pagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = CategoriesFilter
    ordering_fields = ('name', 'parant__id')


    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ['update', 'partial_update', 'list']:
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.IsWaiter,]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow examples on the doc [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples):

Write you own permission and bind to permissions classes.

This would be something like:

```
class CustomPerm(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        is_allowed = request.user.user_permissions.filter(yourpermquery)
        # or
        is_allowed = request.user.groups.filter(name='yourrole')
        return is_allowed
```

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion doesn`t work for me because what i ask is is there any way to set permission (which i already have) to each of the methods. Because as you can see ModelViewSet which i have doesn`t specify GET,POST,DELETE. There are some mixins behind ModelViewSet which i don`t know how to work with. So how can i set these GET,POST,DELETE separately so i hand bind permission to each one. Thank you anyway

Comment: Those mixin provide basic functionnality that relies on GenericViewset, which call all permissions provided in your class attribute array permissions. So what you want is SET permission or check if user HAS permission on a specific view ?